# How to use spinner as time picker in android?

Tags: android, spinner

Is there any way to use The spinner as Time picker in android?
If so how? if not why?

suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time

Answer (score 0):

`Spinner` represents a list of values, from which user can select one. You can use `Spinner` as a time picker if you let users select from a predefined set of time values. But if the logic of application states that users can select any time at all - then `Spinner` is not a good way to go, it will contain too many values and won't be user friendly.